# How to make my sites elements auto adjust to screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have a bit of html the object of interest here being an h2 element.

```
#top-warning{
  justify-content: center !important;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5vw;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: "Penguin Regular";
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

I have this css for an h2 element but whenever the window size is changed, the h2 elements position changes (vertically) until its hidden under other elements. I was wondering how to make every element auto resize to stay scaled properly.

Comment: Use vw for all sizes and paddings and margins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You primarily should be researching CSS properties such as the [display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display). Since you're new I recommend learning the difference between `block` and `inline` so you don't end up making `block` elements children of `inline` elements though it is valid to change an `inline` element inside of another `inline` element to be *displayed as* `block`.

Go to the developer tools in your browser (E.g. `Control` + `Shift` + `C` in Waterfox) and pick an element, set a `background-color` to something with contrast (e.g. `#000`) and then set a `display` property and press the down arrow to cycle through all of the available values that your browser supports to visually see what happens. That being said what you should really learn is about the context of [when and where to use any given HTML5 element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML).

Tip: keep your CSS properties (in the code you posted) alphabetical, it'll help you stay better organized.

Good luck!